# Ansible handlers are not firing?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm pretty new to Ansible (running version 2.2.1.0), and so I have been following the basic directory structure so far.  Recently I tried to move some tasks to the `handlers` area, but I'm getting some odd behavior.

My tree structure looks like:

```
host_inventory
host_vars
site.yml
roles
  common
    handlers
      main.yml
    meta
      main.yml
    tasks
      main.yml
    vars
      main.yml
```

There are really only two relevant files (I think).

This version of tasks/main.yml DOES call the handler:

roles/common/tasks/main.yml:

```
---
  - name: make test file
    shell: "touch /home/hello"
    notify: say goodbye
```

and in roles/common/handlers/main.yml:

```
---
  - name: say goodbye
    shell: "touch /home/goodbye"
```

This does NOT call the handler:

roles/common/tasks/main.yml

```
---
  - name: test for file
    stat:
      path: /home/hello
    notify: say goodbye
```

roles/common/handlers/main.yml

```
---
  - name: say goodbye
    shell: "echo something"
```

I can't understand why my `stat` tasks are not calling their handlers.

Can anyone provide some insight? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers are notified only when task state is `changed`.
In your example `shell` task is always in `changed` state, but `stat` task is always in `ok` state.

See [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to force a task to call a handler, even if the state is not changed?

Comment: No. But you can make a task state to be always `changed` using `changed_when: true` statement.